# Add a property in javascript class component in order to communicate between method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

As title say and below indicate

```
class T extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.a = false;
    }

    methodA {
    //will set 'a' in this method, maybe async.
    }

    methodB {
    // will get 'a' in this method.
    }

    render() {
        return (
                   <div>hello,world</div>
        )
    }
}
```

This looks like a very simple code. However, as the component become more complicated and the logic ascend, we need to add more property to the class to satisfy the communication of the method, like:

```
> class T extends React.Component {
>      constructor(props)
>        this.a = false;
>        this.b = 123;
>        this.c = 'string';
>        this.d = null;
>        this.e = [];
>        ...
>        this.z = ........
>      }
```

Apparently, it is not decent. So, could you please inform me do we have any other solution to replace that? Do we have any decent way to communicate between method in one class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain a bit what are you trying to achieve? How are these methods used? How is the object used?

Comment: Sounds like you might be wanting state?

Comment: I just want to communicate between method without using property,  getter and setter may be a workaround solution, however I want to find a better one nevertheless.

Comment: "communicating between methods" still sounds like an XY problem. An object holds *state* and methods work off that state. If your object just holds pairs of methods that are independent of other methods, it suggests you need an object for each pair. The "bigger" object can then be a composite of those.

Comment: That's basic OOD. If you've got that many properties in your object, then you need to decompose your objects because apparently they're doing too much. In any case without an objective definition of "decent", this question is off-topic as it invites opinions and there is no way of telling which is the winner besides your feeling of its "decency".

Comment: Yes @VLAZ you seem to get my point. In my example, the property just play a global role,  For my point of view, global variable is not recommended in code. But the state is used to render something. I am not talking about render.

Comment: It's a constructive opinion @HereticMonkey thanks.

Comment: @suoyong I meant "state" in the general programming sense, not the React sense (which is still similar but just their implementation). *State* in programming just just the data the application works with. It's not a specific construct or thing. An object *holds state* in the sense that it has *some data* in it. Regardless of what form the data takes. What you describe is an object containing *multiple unrelated* states. Since you've tagged this design-patterns you should be aware of the GoF motto of [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you just want to be able to reference the same variables between different methods in your component? Try using `this.state` in your constructor.

```
Class T extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    a: false,
    b: 123,
    c: 'string',
    ...
  }
}
```

And then you can reference these variables anywhere else in your component...

You change these variables via the `this.setState()` function, which is built in to React.Component.

```
  methodA() {
    return this.state.b * 2
  }

  methodB() {
    this.setState({ c: 'new string' })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Evans From my perspective, 'state' is used to render something. Simply, my question just want to communicate between method in one class.